# Check for out of memory error on open_memstream's FILE operation

Tags: c, linux, posix, glibc, libc

1. Does POSIX guarantees the ferror is set on open_memstream's FILE write operations?
2. How do I check for out of memory condition on FILE operation if the FILE is created with open_memstream?

I used to assume that error should be set on the stream if the internal realloc fails and the error condition could be obtained with ferror, but the following test with glibc 2.31 shows it doesn't do so (Linux overcommit_memory is disabled):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

static char chunk[1024] = {1};

int main(void) {
    size_t sz = 0;
    char *s = NULL;
    FILE *sf = open_memstream(&s, &sz);
    if (!sf) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: ERROR open_memstream failed: %s", (int)__LINE__, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    for (;;) {
        size_t new_n = fwrite(chunk, sizeof chunk, 1, sf);
        if (ferror(sf))
            fprintf(stderr, "%d: ERROR ferror(sf): %s\n", (int)__LINE__, strerror(errno));
        if (new_n == 0)
            break;
    }

    if (fflush(sf))
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: ERROR fflush(sf)\n", (int)__LINE__);
    if (ferror(sf))
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: ERROR ferror(sf)\n", (int)__LINE__);
        
    fprintf(stderr, "%d: writing done %zu\n", (int)__LINE__, sz);
    fclose(sf);
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

```
user@ws:~$ ./a.out 
30: writing done 4347395995
```

glibc ticket for the issue:
https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=26573

Comment: `Linux overcommit_memory is disabled` what it's doing here? `memstream` is totally userspace implementation - there's no kernel involved. `int new_n = fwrite` `fwrite` returns a `size_t`. `(int)__LINE__` why that cast to `int`?

Comment: @KamilCuk 1. but it does realloc - depending on what is set in overcommit_memory, on oom the linux process will be either killed or get NULL pointer returned from the call.
2. +
3. __LINE__ is guaranteed to be an integer constant, but the type is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

> Does POSIX guarantees the ferror is set on open_memstream's FILE write operations?

To my suprise, no, I see nothing in [open_memstream](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open_memstream.html) nor in [ferror](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ferror.html).

Browsing glibc, in [glibc/memstream.c](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/libio/memstream.c#L132) it does not set `_IO_ERR_SEEN` in flags, so `ferror` will not output.

> How do I check for out of memory condition on FILE operation if the FILE is created with open_memstream?

Check if `sz` got incremented. Check `errno`.

Answer (score 0):

The buffer is only observable after `fflush`, and

> Upon successful completion, `fflush()` shall return 0; otherwise, it shall set the error indicator for the stream, return `EOF`, and set `errno` to indicate the error.

This imposes a requirement to set the error indicator.

Comment: as far I as understand, this will indicate an error during fflush operation, not fwrite

Comment: `fwrite` behaves (aside from atomicity of locking) like repeated `fputc`. None of the subject of this question is specific to memory streams. `fputc` must either successfully write or buffer the byte, or report an error and set the error indicator. If it was buffered, `fflush` must report the error and set the error indicator if it cannot be flushed.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE What happens if buffering is disabled on the stream?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Per the spec, you still have to call `fflush` or `fclose` before you can use the result.